# What are the uses of the '<<' operator in ruby

Tags: ruby, operators, midi

I have this sample code, which is essentially just a few basic classes for working with mdii files

```
class Array
    def to_midi(file, note_length='eighth')

        midi_max = 108.0
        midi_min = 21.0

        low, high = min, max
        song = MIDI::Sequence.new

        # Create a new track to hold the melody, running at 120 beats per minute.
        song.tracks << (melody = MIDI::Track.new(song))
        melody.events << MIDI::Tempo.new(MIDI::Tempo.bpm_to_mpq(120))

        # Tell channel zero to use the "piano" sound.
        melody.events << MIDI::ProgramChange.new(0, 0)

        # Create a series of note events that play on channel zero.
        each do |number|
            midi_note = (midi_min + ((number-midi_min) * (midi_max-low)/high)).to_i
            melody.events << MIDI::NoteOnEvent.new(0, midi_note, 127, 0)
            melody.events << MIDI::NoteOffEvent.new(0, midi_note, 127,
            song.note_to_delta(note_length))
        end

        open(file, 'w') { |f| song.write(f) }
    end
end
class TimedTrack < MIDI::Track
    MIDDLE_C = 60
    @@channel_counter=0

    def initialize(number, song)
        super(number)
        @sequence = song
        @time = 0
        @channel = @@channel_counter
        @@channel_counter += 1
    end

    # Tell this track's channel to use the given instrument, and
    # also set the track's instrument display name.
    def instrument=(instrument)
        @events << MIDI::ProgramChange.new(@channel, instrument)
        super(MIDI::GM_PATCH_NAMES[instrument])
    end

      # Add one or more notes to sound simultaneously. Increments the per-track
      # timer so that subsequent notes will sound after this one finishes.
    def add_notes(offsets, velocity=127, duration='quarter')
        offsets = [offsets] unless offsets.respond_to? :each
        offsets.each do |offset|
            event(MIDI::NoteOnEvent.new(@channel, MIDDLE_C + offset, velocity))
        end
        @time += @sequence.note_to_delta(duration)
        offsets.each do |offset|
            event(MIDI::NoteOffEvent.new(@channel, MIDDLE_C + offset, velocity))
        end
        recalc_delta_from_times
    end

      # Uses add_notes to sound a chord (a major triad in root position), using the
      # given note as the low note. Like add_notes, increments the per-track timer.
    def add_major_triad(low_note, velocity=127, duration='quarter')
        add_notes([0, 4, 7].collect { |x| x + low_note }, velocity, duration)
    end

    private

        def event(event)
            @events << event
            event.time_from_start = @time
        end
end
```

most of it makes perfect sense to me except for the lines that use the `<<` operator, from all of my research the only reason to use a `<<` is when your defining a class that will be a singleton. So in what way specifically is the `<<` being used in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<` operator may be used either for bitwise operations (quite unlikely here) or may be overloaded inside the class to match some behavior. In this case there is (probably) an `Array` object and thus the `event` is pushed into the `@events` array via this operator. More info about this use case [can be found here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Take notice, that in future you can bump into other situations where this operator is used and not everytime it will mean same thing - it depends on library creator. The other use case that comes into mind right now can be ActiveRecord Relationships, as `has_many` where also you can use this operator to immediately push an object to relationship and save. More info about this one can be found in [api docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many). Quick sample:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And then somewhere in code you can use:

```
@post = Post.find(10)
@user = User.find(1)
@user.posts << @post
# automatically save the @post object with updated foreign key
```

Comment: Thank you! very well formatted and informative answer!

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/jimm/midilib:

`MIDI::Track` is a track that contains an array of events.

So with `<<` you're adding events to your track. It is the same as 
`melody.events.push(MIDI::NoteOnEvent.new(0, midi_note, 127, 0))`

`<<` could also be used for bit shifting operations

http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/